# Type inheritance in elm

Tags: types, elm

What I am trying to achieve is type inheritance. What I mean by that is that I want to be able to have functions returning "sub-types" and then a function returning the "super-type". Let me give you an example

let's say I have a main View component which returns an Html Msg

```
view:  Model -> Html Msg
view model = 
    div [class "goal-box"] [
      function_a model,
      function_b model
    ]
```

Now I would like `function_a` and `function_b` to each be able to return a subtype of `Msg`

`function_a: Model -> Html AMsg`

`function_b: Model -> Html BMsg`

The reason why I want this is because I want to make sure function_a is limited in what kind of Msg it can produce, and same goes for function_b, but eventually I need a unified view that uses both.

So what came natural was to define Msg as

```
type Msg 
  = AMsg
  | BMsg

type AMsg
  = AnotherMsg Int
  | AgainMsg Int

type BMsg
  = ThisMsg String
  | ThatMsg Int
```

This does not seem to work, as the compiler tells me that it was expecting a return value of type `Html Msg` and not `Html AMsg`.

I hope this is clear. I feel like types are the concept I am struggling with the most coming from JS, but hopefully I am headed in the right direction.

**DISCLAIMER**

I have asked a similar question earlier in the day but I realized I made a mistake and then confused myself a couple of times as I was editing it. So I had to delete it. Apologies in advance to the people that took the time to read it and answer.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do, and the way you tried to do it in the previous question, makes perfect sense and is a feature in OCaml called polymorphic variants. Unfortunately Elm doesn't support it, and that might be because there's some subtle issues with this kind of thing that makes it less appealing, especially for a language aimed at beginners.

Comment: @glennsl yeah, I think that’s what you were trying to explain to me in my other question. Unfortunately I phrased it wrong and I had a couple of other errors that made me believe inheritance was working correctly. I thought about editing the question but it was getting too confusing so I decided to just delete and recreate. Anyhow, Markus answer seems to get the job done, but I certainly wish this was a bit more straight forward. It might happen in the future, we are only at version 0.19 after all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two main issues here.

Firstly `AMsg` and `BMsg` in your `Msg` do not refer to those types, they are just constructors for your `Msg` type.

You need to change this to:

```
type Msg 
  = AMsg AMsg
  | BMsg BMsg
```

Here first `AMsg` and `BMsg` on each line are constructors for `Msg` type, and second ones refer to your other types. After this you can create values like `AMsg (AnotherMsg 34)`.

Secondly you need to use function `Html.map` in your `view` to change message types so that when e.g. `function_a` sends message `AnotherMsg 34` (of type `AMsg`), that will be transformed into `AMsg (AnotherMsg 34)` (of type `Msg`) and so in your `view` all messages are of same type.

Full example code below, with ellie example here: https://ellie-app.com/3TG62zDLvwFa1

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)

type alias Model =
    {}

init : Model
init =
    {}

type Msg 
  = AMsg AMsg
  | BMsg BMsg

type AMsg
  = AnotherMsg Int
  | AgainMsg Int

type BMsg
  = ThisMsg String
  | ThatMsg Int

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model = 
    div [] [
      Html.map AMsg (function_a model),
      Html.map BMsg (function_b model)
    ]

function_a : Model -> Html AMsg
function_a model =
    div [] [ text "A" ]

function_b : Model -> Html BMsg
function_b model =
    div [] [ text "B" ]

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    model

main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! It definitely feels a bit cumbersome, but at least it gets the job done