# Composite Types and Html onInput

Tags: elm

A week ago I finally found a way to split up my messages in different categories ([Here is the SO question where I got my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330051/type-inheritance-in-elm))

Now I have implemented this solution:

```
type Msg 
    = AMsg AMsg
    | BMsg BMsg
    | CMsg CMsg
```

and then I defined AMsg as follows

```
type AMsg
    = ActionOne Int String
    | ActionTwo Int
```

Everything works great except when I use ActionOne with a `onInput` `Html.Event`

```
input [onInput (AMsg (ActionOne model.id))] []
```

This errors out telling me that onInput needs a String -> Msg type but is getting a AMsg type.

This would work just fine if I was using `onClick` for example and pass in the second argument myself

```
input [onClick (AMsg (ActionOne model.id "hello"))] []
```

But since I need to use onInput and that is what passes the second String parameter to ActionOne I am stuck. If I change my types to adapt to this

```
type Msg 
    = AMsg AMsg String
    | BMsg BMsg
    | CMsg CMsg

type AMsg
    = ActionOne Int
    | ActionTwo Int
```

This works, but then i force ActionTwo to also take a string, which i don't want.

Otherwise I am stuck specifying ActionOne directly under Msg

```
type Msg 
        = AMsg AMsg
        | BMsg BMsg
        | CMsg CMsg
        | ActionOne Int String

type AMsg
    = ActionTwo Int
```

I really care about separating Msgs into different categories -- if I want to use elm for a bigger project this seems pretty crucial to me. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function that you pass to [`onInput`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#onInput) has to have the type `String -> msg` (or more specifically in your case, `String -> Msg`.)

You can accomplish that by using a lambda:

```
input [onInput (\str -> (AMsg (ActionOne model.id str)))] []
```

You can also use function composition (the [`<<`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#(%3C%3C)) function) to achieve the same thing without needing to talk about the parameter `str` explicitly:

```
input [ onInput <| AMsg << ActionOne model.id ]
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on answer of Matt McHenry:

Sometimes when you have more complicated cases, it helps to think more closely what the usual simpler syntax actually means. When you have the basic case of

```
type Msg
    = GotInput String
...
input [onInput GotInput] []
```

then `GotInput` here is a function `String -> Msg`. You can also write this out explicitly as:

```
input [onInput (\str -> GotInput str)] []
```

So here you give `onInput` a function which takes `str` parameter and then returns `GotInput str`.

Now that you have this basic function, it can become clearer how to extend this to more complex case - you just change return value and include `str` at correct place in it:

```
input [onInput (\str -> (AMsg (ActionOne model.id str)))] []
```